# Geth.framework for iOS - failed to set up geth instance

Tags: go-ethereum

I tried to use the Geth.framework in iOS to set up geth instance with RPC enabled. I followed the instruction posted on Ethereum github
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Mobile%3A-Introduction, and Peter's (@karalabe) talk titled "Import Geth: Ethereum from Go and beyond".

But I received this compile error in geth instance setup
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
     Geth.run("--ipcdisable --fast --rpc --rpccorsdomain *")
}
The error is: Module Geth has no member named run

The Geth version is the latest version 1.8.2

Any ideas what went wrong? thanks.